# Creating a directive which inherit parent scope as well as have some additional properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i read Angularjs documentation .In directives i can use parent scope for current directive by not speciying scope attribute  like this

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };
});
```

and i can create a directive with isolated scope in this way

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      customerInfo: '=info'
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-customer-iso.html'
  };
});
```

what if i want to inherit all properties of parent scope and want to add some properties related to this directive .i want to create a new scope when this directive is used but not an isolated scope.How to acheive that ??

Comment: What do you mean with "inherit all"? Don't you know which of them you want to use in your directive?

Comment: i am reading documentation.and when we use ng-repeat it inherits parent scope .can similar happen in custom directives also ??

Comment: ng-repeat creates new scopes which are not isolated but inherit from parent scope.

Comment: yes the same i want to create a directive which inherit parent scope not an isolated scope.and create a new scope on the element.

Comment: The question is: why do you want to "import" only one or some of the outer scope properties (customerInfo in your example) and get the rest of the outer scope in a somewhat "dirty" way (without declaring it)?

Comment: i dont want some properties to import .i want all properties to get imported and want to add 2-3 properties which are related to element's scope on which this directive is used.leave the above example because its creating isolated scope.i dont want to create isolated scope.getting my point ??

Comment: You should edit your question and tell us precisely what you want. I think I'm getting your point, but discussing it this way doesn't make much sense. This is not a chat-room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68906/discussion-between-ritesh-mehandiratta-and-hgoebl).

Comment: can u please respond now.i edited it.

Comment: Maybe `scope: true` is what you want, but I'm not sure. You should edit your question so it stands for itself without all those comments. Show us a better example and delete what is not relevant.